# R shiny standalone application using Photon

Tags: r, shiny, photon

I am looking for an easy way to create a standalone application from a Shiny App. I first saw '*Shiny meets electron*' talk by Katie (see Google). After going through their website, I think Photon is their latest method!

I tried to test Photon in it's simplest way but did not succeed.

```
To test Photon, I did the following:

1. install node.js (works, tested 'npm' in CMD line, recognised)

2. install git (works, tested 'git' in CMD line, recognised)

3. install Photon using your instructions

4. Open new basic shinyApplications: RStudio > File > New file > Shiny Web App... >>
--> Name 'PhotonTestApp'
--> multiple fFIle (ui.R/server.R)
--> C:/ShinyApps
Tested to see the app works, the basic Geyser data app.

5. setwd("C:\ShinyApps\PhotonTestApp\")

6. Launch Photon app builder
--> Shiny App Directory: C:/ShinyApps/temp
--> left default NULL in all three package inputs
--> Build
```

I get the following error:

```
> photon:::photon_rstudioaddin()
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3898
[1] "Selected directory: "
[1] "Selected directory: C:/ShinyApps/temp"
Running Photon
Warning in normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
path[1]="C:\ShinyApps\temp/electron-quick-start": The system cannot find the file specified
```

I see that a directory was created: C:\ShinyApps\temp\electron-quick-start\ with a hidden .git directory which is empty.

Some additional info:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Australia.1252 LC_CTYPE=English_Australia.1252 
LC_MONETARY=English_Australia.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C
[5] LC_TIME=English_Australia.1252

attached base packages:
[1] stats graphics grDevices utils datasets methods base

other attached packages:
[1] shiny_1.5.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] Rcpp_1.0.5 rstudioapi_0.11 magrittr_1.5 xtable_1.8-4 R6_2.4.1 rlang_0.4.7 fastmap_1.0.1 stringr_1.4.0 tools_3.6.3
[10] photon_0.0.1 miniUI_0.1.1.1 withr_2.2.0 htmltools_0.5.0 shinyFiles_0.8.0 ellipsis_0.3.1 digest_0.6.25 tibble_3.0.3 lifecycle_0.2.0
[19] crayon_1.3.4 later_1.1.0.1 vctrs_0.3.2 promises_1.1.1 fs_1.4.2 rsconnect_0.8.16 glue_1.4.1 mime_0.9 stringi_1.4.6
[28] compiler_3.6.3 pillar_1.4.6 shinyBS_0.61 jsonlite_1.7.0 httpuv_1.5.4 pkgconfig_2.0.3
```

Comment: On the same boat. I had better success with ```RInno``` https://github.com/ficonsulting/RInno

Answer (score 0):

Open git cmd
change directory to the app.r folder

then run following command:
git clone https://github.com/ColumbusCollaboratory/electron-quick-start

After that launch photon app builder from rstudio and select the directory of app.r which should now also have "electron-quick-start" directory